# Download an public historic mode snapshot

Tags: node

Is there a snapshot of an archive node available somewhere ? It takes weeks to sync from scratch...

There is only full node snapshots at https://tezosshots.com/.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as an "archive snapshot".

If you want an archive mode storage you have two possibilities:

- bootstrap form scratch,
- import a full snapshot and use the `--reconstruct` option to "restore an archive storage" (which is a bit faster but may take days).

If you really want to download a compressed archive of someone's archive node, it is indeed possible but it is not recommended as the data may have been altered.

Comment: Thank you, the second option seems great! Which data/folder would need to be saved if I would like to save my own archive ?

Comment: If you want to backup your own storage you must keep, at least, the `context`, `store` and `version.json`. By default, it is located in `~/.tezos-node`.

Comment: The node delete the data when I paste these files and fodlers. Must I copy also the `alphanet_version` file located in `data` ?