# Import snapshot for an archive node

Tags: node

I am using babylonnet. I installed my node with those steps: https://tezos.gitlab.io/introduction/howtoget.html#build-from-sources

I tried to find an archive node snapshot but I could not find. Because of that I decided to reconstruct a full snapshot to archive. I followed this links.

https://tezos.gitlab.io/user/history_modes.html?highlight=archive#set-up-an-archive-node

[Download an public historic mode snapshot](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/2133/download-an-public-historic-mode-snapshot)

$ tezos-node snapshot import /root/snapshot.full --reconstruct

$ tezos-node: unknown option `--reconstruct'.

Comment: Problem solved. Reconstruct does not work on babylonnet but it works on mainnet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reconstruction feature is not available on Babylonnet. The node was not update as the network will disappear soon.

If really needed, you can use the `master` branch and add the `--network babylonnet` flag to "run babylonnet through the most up to date sources".